# Why does Elixir's String.capitalize() function lowercase remaining letters?

Tags: elixir

Elixir's [`String.capitalize/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#capitalize/2) function "converts the first character in the given string to uppercase and the remainder to lowercase". Would it not be more intuitive to capitalize the first character and leave the remaining characters unchanged? Maybe there is some reasoning I am missing?

The current implementation results in `the local ATM` -> `The local Atm`, `forgotten PIN` -> `Forgotten Pin` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution that does not require calling the undocumented implementation specific `String.Casing`.

```rb
with <<c :: utf8, rest :: binary>> <- "the local ATM",
  do: String.upcase(<<c>>) <> rest

#⇒ "The local ATM"
```

The above works with unicode characters as well (both composed and decomposed):

```rb
with <<c :: utf8, rest :: binary>> <- "über BVG",
  do: String.upcase(<<c>>) <> rest

#⇒ "Über BVG"
```

Comment: This is so cool! I didn't know you could destructure strings like this. Is "destructure" the right word?

Comment: This is pattern matching.

Comment: Why is this `<<c>>` syntax? Where can I find docs on that?

Comment: Sure: https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html. `c` is a byte, `<<c>>` makes it binary.

Comment: @PeacefulJames the question asks why the why the API behaves as it does, and what is more intuitive, not how to do it differently. So if you want to dictate what should happen, then technically the question should be closed for being primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @adam-millerchip I don't "want to dictate what should happen", but thank you for the clarification. I will be more careful about using the word "should" in the future. Thanks for your helpful contribution.

Answer (score 4):

This is elixir api that get's called for capitalisation.

```
def capitalize(string, mode) when is_binary(string) do
    {char, rest} = String.Casing.titlecase_once(string, mode)
    char <> downcase(rest, mode)
end
```

If we want to fulfil your requirement which is to capitalise only first letter than we could perform something like this. Here we only removed extra down casing call so we have only made this code more robust when it comes to performance.

```
def capitalize_only_first(string, mode) when is_binary(string) do
    {char, rest} = String.Casing.titlecase_once(string, mode)
    char <> rest
end
```

Second implementation is better from performance point of view. So, I believe only reason to keep this `capitalize/2` implementation by elixir is because majority of developer's would expect it to work this way.

This answer made me generally curious around reasoning that could have gone around it. :)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking to do this without writing custom function, here is how I do this when I need it:

```elixir
"the local ATM"
|> String.Casing.titlecase_once(:default)
|> Tuple.to_list 
|> Enum.join
```

JFYI for anyone googling this :)

UPDATE: don't do this! As per https://elixirforum.com/t/string-capitalize-should-have-a-leave-the-rest-of-the-word-alone-option/31095/2?u=slouchpie it is dangerous to use `Casing.titlecase_once`

Answer (score 0):

For person who was looking for capitalizing every word in string (and could not find).

```
capitalize_words = fn string ->
  String.split(" ")
    |> Enum.map(& String.capitalize(&1))  # or Enum.map(& (String.capitalize/1))
    |> Enum.join(" ")
end
```

as result:

```
iex> capitalize_words.("hello to every human being!")
"Hello To Every Human Being!"
```